# Keyboard shortcut in Eclipse to move file from one editor to another

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, shortcut

Does anyone know if there is a keystroke in eclipse that will, if you have two editor panes, move the file you're looking at from the editor pane it is on to the other one?

**Use Case:** I have three files open: two on the left and one on the right. I'm looking at one on the left. I press  and it moves the file from the left to the right so now there would be one on the left and two on the right.

Comment: have you found the answer?